# Show or hide Panel based on Button click from previous page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pageload, buttonclick

I have a link button control on my home page side bar nav. When a user clicks this button they are taken to another page called CRM. I have many panels with grids on the CRM page. Which are all set to be hidden or shown on the Page Load event.

However when a user clicks a specific link button from the home page and is taken to the CRM page, I need to hide all grids and show a new panel of text boxes.

In a similar task, I have a radio button on a page and if a user clicks a specific Link Button from another Page, I need the radio button to be clicked or pressed already when the user arrives on the page.

I hope this makes sense.

How do I determine if the user is coming to my CRM page because he clicked one specific  button in my sidebar navigation and show/hide panels based on that? 
Same for radio button.
How do I set `radiobutton.clicked = true;` If the user clicked a specific linkbutton from a previous page?

Thanks
EB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a value through the query string, session, cookie, or cache, to indicate they selected the feature that the radio button needs to be checked.  Nothing exists by default to automatically trigger it.  So you set:

```
Session("ClickRadioButton") = true
```

and in the code, on page init, for the first time, do:

```
if (Session("ClickRadioButton") = true) then
   radiobutton.Checked = true
end if
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply.I Am trying the code for the first part of my question. On the first Page inside the linkbutton click event I set `Session["lnkBtnNewCust_Click"] = true;`  And On the next Page I do this: `protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
    {

     if (Convert.ToBoolean(Session["lnkBtnNewCust_Click"]) == true)
       {
              
                pnlAdmin.Visible = false;

            }

        }  
    }`    And Nothing happens the Panel is still showing even though I 'm setting it to Visible.false;

Comment: I think PreInit is too early; you would have to do it in the Init event, or possibly the Load event.